# How to remove the right click menu in VLC Media Player?

Tags: contextmenu, vlc, right-click, skin, video-player

I am adapting VLC to make a custom video player. I chose VLC because of its ability to play lots of formats, and because it allows me develop a custom skin for it very easily.

But I also want to restrict user access to the file system, for which I need to disable the right click menu. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 59):

1. Open the **Registry Editor** (`regedit.exe`). Find `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell`
2. Under this key find each VLC key you would like to remove from folder context menus
3. (Optional) right-click each key and choose **Export**. Save the exported reg files as `PlayWithVLC-dir` and `AddToPlaylistVLC-dir`. These `.reg` files can later be used to restore the context menu entries.
4. Delete the key

Unfortunately VLC doesn't have an Preferences option to toggle this.

Solution found in the [Remove context menu](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=82274) forum thread.

Comment: Thanks for the instructions.

Comment: Probably want to do this under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\Directory\shell, as HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT is a [merged view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sysinfo/merged-view-of-hkey-classes-root) of HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes, and therefore shouldn't be edited directly.

Comment: You may be correct for the backup, but wouldn't this only matter if you're adding keys? (in which case i assume they'd be added to both locations.) For deleting keys it shouldn't matter what view you go through to find them so long as they're removed right?

Comment: Is this even answering the question? Or what is the original question? I thought OP was asking about context menu while playing videos inside VLC?

Answer (score 24):

Instead of playing around in the registry:

1. **uninstall VLC**. You will be asked, if you want to keep your user settings. Say yes if you want to.
2. **download VLC installer** again http://www.videolan.org/vlc/
3. during installation **uncheck** the **"Context Menus"** install option.

For some people it was possible to skip step 1. But that may not work always.

[image]

Comment: You don't even have to uninstall VLC first, you can just run the installer, and choose 'Add/Rmove/Reinstall components'.

Comment: @BetaLyte that is even better!

Comment: For some reason, this didn't work for me. It did not remove the context menu entries when right clicking on a directory in file explorer. I had to delete the registry keys manually for those.

Comment: @jippyjoe4 hm, I modified this yesterday. yesterday the first step was to uninstall VLC before... maybe in some cases this is required. i will go back to the previous edit then.

Answer (score 19):

Use this PowerShell script using an elevated console (RunAs Admin)

```
New-PSDrive -Name HKCR -PSProvider Registry -Root HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT #not permanent
Remove-Item HKCR:\Directory\shell\AddToPlaylistVLC\ -Recurse
Remove-Item HKCR:\Directory\shell\PlayWithVLC\ -Recurse
```

Answer (score 5):

Or just use [CCleaner](https://www.ccleaner.com/):

1. Open CCleaner,
2. Chose Tools,
3. Select Startup,
4. Go to context menu column on the right,
5. Find what program you want to disable or delete from context menu,

Comment: Just to bring up the point. CCleaner could still have malware in it. https://www.pcworld.com/article/3225407/security/ccleaner-downloads-infected-malware.html

Answer (score 2):

Create or download the following `.reg` files with the respective content:

`DELETE-AddToPlaylistVLC` ([download](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/qubodup/reg/main/DELETE-AddToPlaylistVLC.reg))

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\AddToPlaylistVLC]
```

`DELETE-PlayWithVLC.reg` ([download](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/qubodup/reg/main/DELETE-PlayWithVLC.reg))

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\PlayWithVLC]
```

Then double-click for the menu entry you want removed.